# Chrome USB-API - Digital Fingeprint (Futronic)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, usb, fingerprint

I'm trying to use usb-api a fingerprint (Futronic) using Chrome.

I was able to select and open the device.

But I can't start or enable the reader at fingerprint.

I had tryied:

```
          var transferInfoOut = {
              "direction": "out",
              "endpoint": 1,
              "data": new Uint8Array([4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]).buffer
            };               

           chrome.usb.bulkTransfer(connectionHandle, transferInfoOut, function(transferInfo){


               var transferInfoInfo = { 'transferInfo': transferInfo, 'index': undefined };
               console.log('reading...')
               console.info(transferInfoInfo); 
           });
```

But i alwas get the same error:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running usb.bulkTransfer: Transfer
>   failed.
>       at Object.callback (chrome-extension://fggpkikcnbdlckieakllnflnkmfbfobf/script.js:192:27)reportIfUnchecked
>   @ extensions::lastError:133handleResponse @ extensions::sendRequest:78

Comment: It may not be the solution but have you installed the Futronic fingerprint API in your workstation?

Comment: @carlos.hager did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Hello guys, so I didn't fix it at that time. I found another solution instead of sending commands straight to the device. My problem had begun because we used to use applets to use the API, so we were testing new approaches but at the end we decided to create a jar client and execute it via jnlp.